# Display popup in Win32 Console Application

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I display a popup window in a Win32 Console application in Microsoft Visual C++?
This is for building a drowsiness detection system using OpenCv.

Comment: Do you want a modal popup?

Comment: I just want to display the message "The driver is sleeping!!"

Comment: If(eyesclosed for a certain no of frames){Display popup(Sleeping);}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
MessageBox( nullptr, TEXT( "The driver is sleeping!!" ), TEXT( "Message" ), MB_OK );
```

Make sure to include windows.h. The thread you call this on will block.

Comment: thats not a popup window. its a message box.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: it is an OS-provided popup.  "I just want to display the message ..." is exactly what `MessageBox()` is designed for.

Answer (score 4):

You can just call something like :-

```
MessageBoxA(NULL, "Wake Up!", "Alert!", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

You have to include  for this to work.

These APIS still work from a console app.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <windows.h> 

int main() { 
        MessageBox(NULL, L"The message", L"The caption", MB_OK);

        return 0; 
}
```

remember to link with `user32.lib`